# "Build" JS variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm having problem for a long time and I would like to solve it now.
In php, if you want to retreive variable $var123, you could do it this way

```
$varname = "var123";
$var = $$varname;
```

How could I do the same in js and/or jquery?

Comment: This is a terrible idea even in PHP.

Comment: why would it be terrible ideA?

Comment: That's just one of those baloney "blabla is evil" memes. Sometimes there are exceptional circumstances where you can and should use variable variable names. (Namely when it reduces cumbersome workarounds.)

Comment: But 99% of the cases, an associative array works just as well, avoids littering the namespace, and isn't as likely to be re-implemented with a nonvalidating use of `eval` by poor souls who have heard of neither. There's also zero reason to include them in a new language (if it has associative arrays), as all features start out with a score -100 and this one hardly gets above -99 overall. These "exceptional circumstances" are truly very exceptional and I'd never trust anyone who has an ounce of beginnerness at them to recognize such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var varname = 'var123';
var value = window[varname];
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll accept your answer ASAP - you were the fastest

Answer (score 1):

If this variable in global scope, you can do something like:

```
window['variableName']
```

But i'm not sure that it's possible to implement this if you're not in global scope (in function body)

Answer (score 0):

As long  as the variable exists in <strike>your current scope</strike> global scope, you can access it using window.

```
var textVar = 'The text inside';
alert(window['textVar']);
```

Comment: -1 Wrong, this will only work for properties of `window` (i.e. global variables). Try `(function () { var a = 0; alert(window['a']) } )()`

Comment: @delnan yup you're correct. I've updated. Thanks for the heads up